# My camera app keeps replacing pictures I took on my Samsung Note 22 Ultra

Tags: camera, samsung-notes

I have a very weird and extremely annoying problem with the camera app on my Samsung Note 22 Ultra.

When I take pictures with my camera app, it first shows the correct picture that I want to take when I press the camera shutter button. However, after a few seconds of showing that picture, it changes to a picture taken a few moments later, deleting the original picture.

So my question is, what might be the issue of this and if I have some weird setting turned on? It is evident that the camera takes the initial picture that I want (as it is displayed on my screen for a few seconds), but then I have no idea why it switches to another picture and the original picture is lost. This happens when I take pictures of moving subjects.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: I remember that some camera apps have AI features where the app takes multiple pictures when triggered and then chose then uses AI to chose the "best" one of the series. Alternatively you could try to simply delete app data of the camera app. That will reset the camera app to (hopefully) safe default settings.

Comment: Is it possible that what you call the "preview" function is actually a "naming" function, in which you can substitute with a meaningful name? Possibly it is substituting a previous picture's name from a list because an errant thumb or finger triggered it?

Comment: Might be related: [Galaxy Camera: How Do I use the Best Photo feature?](https://www.samsung.com/za/support/mobile-devices/galaxy-camera-how-do-i-use-the-best-photo-feature/), though I can't say if this feature is still available in the latest Galaxy Camera.